# Knockout Filtering on Observable Array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, filter, observable

I've started learning Knockout and I'm having some trouble filtering an observable array on a button click and displaying the results.

This is my model:

```
function Product(data) {     
    this.id = data.id;
    this.name = data.name;
    this.price = data.price;
    this.description = data.desc;
    this.image = data.image;
    this.genre = data.genre;
    this.show = data.show;
    this.offer_desc = data.offer_desc;
    this.offer_id = data.offer_id;
}

function ProductModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.products = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.getJSON('../PHP/Utilities.php?json=true', function(json) {
       var mappedProducts = $.map(json, function(item) { return new Product(item) });
       self.products(mappedProducts);
    });

    self.filterProducts = ko.computed(function(genre) {
        if(typeof genre === 'undefined') {
            return self.products(); //initial load when no genre filter is specified
        } else {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.products(), function(prod) {
                return prod.genre = genre;
            });
        }
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ProductModel());
```

This is the html:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: filterProducts">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
        <img data-bind="attr:{src: '../images/' + image, alt: name}" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2" data-bind="text: name"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1" data-bind="text: price"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3" data-bind="text: description"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1" data-bind='text: offer_id'>                  
        <div class="col-md-2" data-bind="text: genre"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1" data-bind="text: show"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm also not sure how to bind a click function to filter the products on genre. I thought something like this...but it doesn't work

```
<button data-bind="click: filter('1')"> Filter </button>

self.filter = function(genre) {
    self.filterProducts(genre);
}
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You cannot have a function with parameters inside a `ko.computed`.

What you need is store the current filter in a new property and use that in your computed

```
function ProductModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.products = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.currentFilter = ko.observable(); // property to store the filter

    //...

    self.filterProducts = ko.computed(function() {
        if(!self.currentFilter()) {
            return self.products(); 
        } else {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.products(), function(prod) {
                return prod.genre == self.currentFilter();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

And in your `click` handler just set the current filter:

```
<button data-bind="click: function() { filter('1') }"> Filter </button>

self.filter = function(genre) {
    self.currentFilter(genre);
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R8dpQ/)

Note the `function() {  }` in needed if you want to pass additional arguments a in `click` binding (see also in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note_2_accessing_the_event_object_or_passing_more_parameters)), otherwise Knockout would execute your function when it parses the binding and not when you click on the button.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I still can't get the filter working. 
I changed the 'return prod.genre = currentFilter() to return ... self.currentFilter() because it threw an error.

Otherwise, no errors are thrown, the product list just doesn't update. 

Also, what is the reason for adding the function(){} around the click binding?

Thanks.

Comment: @SkelDave yes the `self.currentFilter()` was a typo. But you don't just need to return you need to write `return prod.genre == self.currentFilter();` a single `=` is the assigment and the double `==` is the equality check. I've added a working example and also some explanation of the  `function(){}`

Comment: Thank you, that has sorted out the problem!

Answer (score 6):

You might want to have a look at [Knockout Projections](https://github.com/stevesanderson/knockout-projections) plugin from the author of original knockout. It has performance advantages in scenarios with **large collections**. See [blogpost](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/12/03/knockout-projections-a-plugin-for-efficient-observable-array-transformations/) for more details.

```
self.filterProducts = self.products.filter(function(prod) {
    return !self.currentFilter() || prod.genre == self.currentFilter();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

First you mis-understand/use for `computed Observables`. From [KnockoutJS documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html):

> these are functions that are dependent on one or more other
>   observables, and will automatically update whenever any of these
>   dependencies change.

Your computed observable `filterProducts` depend on observable array `products` which you **does not change**, you just read it's value. So, there is nothing to notify `filterProducts` to be re-evaluated.

So, what would be quick simple fix?

1. Define a new observable object `filteredGenre` on which your `filterProducts` will depend on.
2. Change `filterProducts` so that it check for the value of `filteredGenre` and based on, it return filtered products.
3. Change `filter` function so that when it get new `genre` it changes `filteredGenre` which would result in re-evaluating of computed `filterProducts`

I hope you got the idea.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the points and I had also misunderstood computed Observables. I followed your instructions in my implementation, works as expected.